# Google api auto-complete error

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, maps

I am using Google autocomplete api from this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#introduction

My observations is autocomplete works some times (randomly) and then fails with this error if I do inspect of the web-page.

**"InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement"**

I am not sure exactly what code should I paste here, because I do not think its a code related error since it works many times. I think its some dependency error.

Any pointers to resolve are appreciated. I have already inquired with some web-developers, and tried google, but not much help.

Many thanks
Mrunal

Comment: Ok. Never mind. the problem was solved. My api referral script and the corresponding local script were added at the start of the html page, which I moved to the end of the page and it fixed the issue

Comment: I think the problem was some times DOM was not completely loaded before the script executed that made script not find some elements and threw the error